# Can not open Excel file saved with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using an excel file with graphs and tables in different worksheets (3 sheets of data and 10 sheets of graphs only). When I only load and save the excel file, I have an error message that says that the new excel file is corrupted and needs to be repaired.
I tried to delete one and more sheets randomly and it works fine. Is openpyxl limited in memory or the version of excel it uses is an old one?
I searched for this problem online and many posts exists but none have an answer to my problem.
Moreover, when i only open and save the file with excel, the output file is smaller than the input file with a difference of 1.5 Mo in general.

Here's my code:

```
Wbdata=wb.load_workbook('Test_Resultat.xlsx')
Wbdata.save('Test_Resultat_copie.xlsx')
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try use ```Wbdata.close()``` after saving it?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work either

Answer (score -1):

The format of MSOffice document is indeed documented, but the way Microsoft genuine applications interpret it is not. It can even change across versions without notice from Microsoft.

Said differently, if you only have a very trivial document produced by openpyxl (broadly skeaking nothing more that what you could save in a CSV file, that is raw data with no formatting), it will probably be processed without any warning by Excel. But as soon as you use formatting or links between sheets, the risk for the way openpyxl choosed to write the document to be different from the way genuine Excel does is high. The document can still be interpreted, but the fact that it was not written by a genuine Microsoft app is visible. And Microsoft fellows choosed to warn the user of that difference by saying that the document is corrupted and needs to be repaired.

If you are the only user of the produced document, or if you can explain your users that the message is normal *for the current production chain* just move on: Excel will rewrite *its* file according to *its own* way, and there will be no problem.

If you want to largely deploy the result files and cannot accept the message, then you will have to install a *last translation step* in your chain on a true Microsoft system. Neither very complex nor very resource consuming, because it can easily be automated. But it requires some licenses and a minimum Microsoft development tools knowledge...

Can you now guess a possible reason for the *corruption* message ;-) ?

Disclaimer: that last line is only my own opinion...

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but what bothers me is the memory problem. By just reading and saving the file, the output file will be smaller than the input file in any case (which is not normal and can be part of the problem). Moreover, when i slightly decrease the weight of the file, I don't have the message anymore. I reduced the weight of the file by deleting only one sheet randomly (I tried them all, so this is a memory issue for me).